# How do I remove bloomy rind without wasting too much cheese?

Tags: cheese

Suppose I have a cheese that has a [bloomy rind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloomy_rind) such as camembert or brie. I want to completely remove the rind before eating. What are some reliable methods I can use to remove the rind without wasting too much cheese? I could cut off the rind using a knife, but that wastes a lot of cheese.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the cheese is very **cold** (even frozen), use a **sharp knife** and it will be easier to cut the rind off more precisely, to waste less cheese.

(*I assume you're aware that the rind is edible and indeed enjoyed by many people. Another way to avoid wasting cheese would be to find a rind-eating friend to share your cheese with.*)

Comment: @Flux If my answer was helpful you can mark it as accepted using the tick mark under the voting arrows. :)